# I am working with code but is does not provide me desire result. Can you please tell me how to Scrape Facebook comments text from fb live or post?

Tags: selenium, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, facebook-comments

I want to scrape facebook comments from fb live or post,..is there any way to get this? If anyone know please help me.

I am using this but it does not working.

Code:

```
   comments = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.UFICommentBody span')
   print("Comment found " +str(len(comments)))
   for x in range(len(comments)): 
   print (comments[x])
```

Output:

```
  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0ea2c4e211c05d504536a1bef2259260", element="a0a4c59f-9c84-4a5c-855d-3ba51cea249a")>
  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0ea2c4e211c05d504536a1bef2259260", element="504c6ef2-e9fe-42b7-9f68-dcee5e7dbfde")>
  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0ea2c4e211c05d504536a1bef2259260", element="06d25f07-3a20-4783-98d7-f9c0ae01c230")>
  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0ea2c4e211c05d504536a1bef2259260", element="5e6b1e94-fee8-4636-9d9e-fd992c945c19")>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to print text from your list then you can use for loop to retrieve each element through your list and then use `.text` with each object to print assoociated text.

```
print("Comment found " +str(len(comments)))
   for x in range(len(comments)): 
   print (comments[x].text)
```

or

```
 print("Comment found " +str(len(comments)))
       for x in range(len(comments)): 
       print (x.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text from the elements, you need to do this (assuming you are using python):

```
 print (comments[x].text)
```